# How do I run different playbooks in different guests in a vagrant environment

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I have a Vagrantfile that sets up two guests. I would like to provision different playbooks against each guest.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "awx" do |awx|
    awx.vm.box = "centos/7"
    awx.vm.hostname ="awx"
    awx.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
    config.vm.provision "ansible"  do |master|
      master.playbook = "awx.yml"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "test"  do |test|
    test.vm.box = "centos/7"
    test.vm.hostname = "test"
    test.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.11"
    config.vm.provision "ansible"  do |slave|
      slave.playbook = "httpd-server.yml"
    end 

  end
end
```

The the first playbook executes against the first node as expected. However, both playbooks execute against the second node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the outer scope iteration variable `config` instead of the inner scope iteration variables for your method invocations. These would lock down the scope of your Ansible provisioner to only vagrant machines defined within that scope. For example, to rectify your problem we would do:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "awx" do |awx|
    awx.vm.box = "centos/7"
    awx.vm.hostname ="awx"
    awx.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
    awx.vm.provision "ansible"  do |master| # inner scope iter var awx
      master.playbook = "awx.yml"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "test"  do |test|
    test.vm.box = "centos/7"
    test.vm.hostname = "test"
    test.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.11"
    test.vm.provision "ansible"  do |slave| # inner scope iter var test
      slave.playbook = "httpd-server.yml"
    end 
  end
end
```